# Avoid repetition in JSON

Tags: json, graph

When you have a javascript object tree where some branches are repeated, is there a to tool which could output it withouth the repetition?

example:

situation as is:

```
var a = new MyHugeObject();
var b = "Hello world!";
var c = 42;
var result = { main: a, all: [a, b, c] };
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

where output would contain the whole JSON of `a` twice

```
{main:/* lot of json removed*/,all:[/* same lot of json removed*/,"Hello world!",42]}
```

sitution to be:

```
var a = new MyHugeObject();
var b = "Hello world!";
var c = 42;
var result = { main: a, all: [a, b, c] };
console.log(someMagic(result));
```

where output would contain the whole JSON of `a`

```
{main:/* lot of json removed*/,all:reference-to-main,"Hello world!",42]}
```

I took a glimpse at falcor's json graph, but I didn't dig very deep and was left with the impression that it wouldn't eventually just let me convert an existing object to an optimized json.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function to convert the object into a new one which is the representation of the former including `{ $ref: **json pointer** }` where there are cycle. It's not perfect yet (optimization, support of specials characters to escape) but it does a job good enough for my current need.

It's available on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-json-refs) and source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/serge-jacquemin-busi/object-to-json-refs).